# slide menu won't slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a side menu in css and want to use the the tranform: translateX() property to slide it on and off on the page. I'm using a checkbox to toggle the menu on and off. So I thought I can use javascript to make it function, but it's not working. Can you edit the transform property through javascript?

here's the code...

```
window.onload = function () {
        var toggle_btn = document.getElementById('toggle_btn');
        var slide_menu = document.getElementById('slide_menu');

        var checked = function() {
            toggle_btn.checked = true;
        };

        if (checked === true) {
            slide_menu.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
        } else {
            slide_menu.style.transform = "translateX(-200px)";
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please share your HTML/CSS as well. A jsfiddle would also help us play with the code and workout a solution to your issue.

Comment: maybe it needs oiling lol. better to use `transform:none` btw, or remove the style altogether. just make sure you have transition applied via CSS

Comment: are you shure that `function(){toggle_btn.checked = true;}` will return something except true?

Comment: what is `checked`? makes no sense, you don't even run that function! use `checked()`. you don't even need a function anyway, just use `toggle_btn.checked` and get over with it

Comment: Any reason to use the jQuery tag ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=epSRmQ9gCq

Comment: I posted the link. It should work...

Comment: vals I don't know jQuery unfortunately. I need to learn it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var toggle_btn = document.getElementById('toggle_btn'),
        slide_menu = document.getElementById('slide_menu');

    slide_menu.style.transform = toggle_btn.checked=== true ? "none" : "translateX(-200px)";

};
```

BTW - you don't need javascript for this: http://jsfiddle.net/w5te8qqx/1/